# Portable ubuntu on internal hard drive and portability question

Tags: boot, hard-drive, portable

Happy new year to everyone! I read the post about installing on an external usb drive, but what I want to do is install and I should say not install but make one of the hard drive partitions like an ubuntu installation usb. I tried using rufus, unetbootin, but only on unetbootin I have the option for make a bootable partition for later instalation of ubuntu on the local hard drive, however the only partition that it gives me to use is the one windows is installed on.

I need to put a portable version on my internal hard drive, in case I change the hard drive to a different PC, ubuntu will still work, just like the windows to go workspace.

Also if I have installed ubuntu on my local drive already, if I change the drive, will ubuntu still work with the new computer?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a portable Ubuntu internal hard drive. I don't think such a thing exist. As long as your current and future PCs have hardware that has open-source drivers, installed Ubuntu in the internal hard drive should work in the future PC.

Comment: There are several ways to do this. Search for "ubuntu create read-only file system"

Comment: The only way I have managed to install a Live or Persistent system on an internal drive is to clone it from an external drive. This would be difficult if Windows is already on the disk. Persistent Ubuntu should work on any computer you plug it into as long as the computer meets the minimum spec's and the installer is BIOS/UEFI compatible such as mkusb. What is wrong with doing a normal dual boot install to one of the partitions?

Comment: Perhaps wubiuefi would suit your needs: https://github.com/hakuna-m/wubiuefi/wiki#releases

Comment: I am sorry for taking so long to reply. I have a lot of things to do. The idea is if I move my hard disk to a new computer, Ubuntu to still be working. That way I will not have to reinstall everything, but can just plug in the new hard drive to the new hardware and start using it. It is a very good function that Ubuntu should consider (all you have to do is add support to rufus for using a whole partition of the hard drive instead of a USB drive.

Comment: This is very convinient for me. I intend to pass on Ubuntu, because Windows 10 is junk. Also if something happens I can use the Ubuntu installation in order to make a recovery CD or something to fix Windows. It becomes very valuable. In order to increase the Ubuntu sales, I suggest you start offering students to make applications for free or port the existing ones (especially in China with 1.5 billion people). This way you will increase your popularity. In order to solve the biggest problem with Ubuntu (which is popularity) you should make Android apps compatible fully and add the App store.

Comment: If I need to have only Ubuntu on the hard drive, that is OK. As long as it works, when I plug it in on the new computer. I post 3 comments, because of the character limitation and 5 minute edit time.